# Javascript: Setting one value in an array sets all others to that value

Tags: javascript, arrays

when I try to set a value in an array in javascript, all the other "adjacent" values change as well.

```
var screenData = [];
function init() {
    var properties = { "property": "value" }
    for( i = 0; i < 35; i++ ) {
        var row = [];
        for( j = 0; j < 19; j++ ) {
            row.push(properties);
        }
        screenData.push(row);
    }
}
init();
screenData[0][0].property = "othervalue";
alert(screenData[0][1].property);
```

The alert will return `othervalue` although it should be `value` :(

Did I just oversee something or is this a bug?

Any help would be appreciated :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are pushing the same object in each iteration, you should [clone the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) and then `push` the cloned object. Currently all the array's elements refer to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you reference the same object (`properties`) thus each time you modify `property` it is updated everywhere.

```
function init() {
    for( i = 0; i < 35; i++ ) {
        var row = [];
        for( j = 0; j < 19; j++ ) {
            row.push({ property: 'value' });
        }
        screenData.push(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. You are pushing a **reference to the the properties object** into your array. This means your array contains several references to the same object. You can solve this by resetting the properties variable inside the for loop.

```
function init() {
   for( i = 0; i < 35; i++ ) {
        var row = [];
        for( j = 0; j < 19; j++ ) {
            var properties = { "property": "value" }
            row.push(properties);
        }
        screenData.push(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead this:

```
for( j = 0; j < 19; j++ ) {
        row.push(properties);
    }
screenData.push(row);
```

It could be:

```
for( j = 0; j < 19; j++ ) {
        row.push(_clone(properties));
    }
screenData.push(row);
```

Where _.clone(object) is Underscore library function: [UnderScore _clone references](http://underscorejs.org/#clone)

Note that, as you can read here, nested objects (not in this case, because this is string) are referenced not copied.